# How can I view an App's full name?

Tags: ios, springboard

On my iPhone's home screen, I have two versions of Cut The Rope 2 which have identical icons and display names.

One version is the full version of [Cut The Rope 2](https://appsto.re/us/IG6OO.i), while the other is the F2P [Cut The Rope 2: Om Nom's Adventure](https://appsto.re/us/ghneV.i).

Because the display names are identical, I'm not sure which version I should delete.

**Is there a way to view an App's full name?**

[image: Duplicate Cut The Rope 2]

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way you can tell from the Home screen.

One way to ensure you delete the correct one is to start the app and look at the title.

Another way is to move one of them to a folder and then do a Spotlight search. Spotlight will show you the full name (up to the 30 or 50 character limit, I don't recall the actual number right now) as well as the folder name if it's in a folder.

Comment: They both list the same title when started, and in the "Manage Storage" menu

Comment: What about moving one to a folder, does that show the full name?

Comment: Neither [spotlight search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQto0.png) or [folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds9ju.jpg) show the full title.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "Om Nom"?

Comment: It's up to the developer to use proper naming of their app, both the displayed and internal name. If this developer used names that are too similar then there might not be anything you can do about it.  On my iPad, Spotlight shows longer names than those displayed on the Home screen.